# How do I delay delivery of a JMS message using HornetQ?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, hornetq

Basically, I want the HornetQ equivalent of:

```
message.setLongProperty("JMS_JBOSS_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + processingDelayInMS);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [HornetQ scheduled delivery property](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html_single/index.html#d0e5312): "_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY" (or the constant Message.HDR_SCHEDULED_DELIVERY_TIME).